# Continuous page numbering in thesis

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, thesis

I need to have continuous page numbering from start to end for my thesis, i.e. the title page should be page number 1 and if there are 100 pages in all, the last page should be numbered 100. Thus every single page needs to be numbered. I found the following to work for this:

```
\makeatletter
 \renewenvironment{titlepage}
  {%
   \if@twocolumn
    \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
   \else
    \@restonecolfalse\newpage
   \fi
   % \thispagestyle{empty}% remove the empty page style
   %\setcounter{page}\z@ %remove the counter reset
 }%
\makeatother
```

Now, above segment gives me a continuous page numbering (at the bottom of each page) without any problem.  But when I try to generate the 'Table of contents' (toc) for the thesis, I see that the 'toc' displays incorrect page number against the first section of the first chapter (which is the by default the first entry in the toc). Is there something I am missing? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should post an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so we can see which packages you use. With [Komascript](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) and their `scrheadings` this should not be a problem.

Comment: Can you give a Minimal Working Example demonstrating the problem? Right now, people don't even know what document class you are using or whether you've identified any particular packages you load as contributing to the issue.